# Run pdflatex command in Swift with App Sandbox turned ON

Tags: swift, latex, pdflatex

I want to compile a latex file in swift, I am able to compile the file if the application has the App Sandbox OFF.

If I turn App Sandbox ON and try to compile I get the error: "launch path not accessible"

How can I run the pdflatex command to compile the latex file with the App Sandbox turned ON?

Below is the method the I use and it works with App Sandbox turned OFF.

```
let latexCmd = "/Users/user/Desktop/test/article.tex"
let logText:String = self.runTerminal(command: latexCmd)

func runTerminal(command: String)->String{

    let pipe:Pipe = Pipe()
    let task:Process = Process()

    task.launchPath = "/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex"
    task.arguments = ["-file-line-error", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "-synctex=1", command]
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.currentDirectoryPath = "/Users/user/Desktop/test"

    task.launch()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))

    return output!
}
```